# not enough argument, self-defined function in matlab

Tags: matlab, arguments

I am a newbie of matlab and am trying to define a pretty complex function to plot it. The content of file is following:

```
function [res] = distribution (input)
a = factorial(30)
b = factorial(input) * factorial(30-input)
c = power(0.05, input)
d = power(0.95, 30-input)

a/b*c*d
end
```

in the file named distribution with .m extension. But when I run it error returns: "Error using distribution (line 4). Not enough input arguments."

I read through the "Getting Started" and find no solution. Does anyone have suggestions on this?

Comment: how do you call your distribution function ?

Answer (score 3):

The name of the single argument to your function `distribution(..)`, namely argument `input`, conflicts with [the existing native `input` command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) of Matlab,

> `input`: Prompt for user input.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> x = input(prompt)
> ```

Try choosing a different name of this argument (in example below: `foo`), and also remember to return your result by assigning it to the return variable `res`:

```
function res = distribution (foo)
    a = factorial(30);
    b = factorial(foo) * factorial(30-foo);
    c = power(0.05, foo);
    d = power(0.95, 30-foo);

    res = a/b*c*d; % <--- note, return parameter assignment
end
```